# is there a python code to reformat an excel sheet? i currently have downloaded data but it is all in one column and would like to separate by keyword

Tags: python, excel

below is an example of what the data is currently arranged like and i would like ti separate each of these lines into their own column - it is separated by company after the "Certified" line is a new company

```
ABC
Main Rd
PO Box 15
"City, WI 12315"
UNITED STATES

www.abc.com

(555) 987-6543(p)
(555) 987-6543(f)

Specialties:
"term, term, term, term, term, term, term, term"

Certified StaffSTARS ProgramAward Winner
"XYZ"
First St
PO Box 555555
"Houston, TX 12345"
UNITED STATES

www.xyz.com

(555) 123-4567(p)
(555) 123-4567(f)

Specialties:
"term, term, term, term, term, term, term"

Certified Staff Award Winner
```

[image]
each new company appears at the line after certified

how can i separate this such that it would look like the following (please keep in mind the data is thousands of rows long):
[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your data is stocked in a text file, you can read the lines, remove the double quotes on each line, filter the empty lines, define "Certified" as an end of line, and then simply add a delimiter between each value.

Something like this :

```
fromFile = "myfile.txt"
targetFile = "data.csv"
delimiter = ";"

with open(fromFile) as read_file:
    lines = [line.rstrip().replace('"', '') for line in read_file]
    
with open(targetFile, 'w') as write_file:
    write_file.write(delimiter.join(['\n' if 'Certified' in s else s for s in filter(lambda x: x!='',lines)]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that no data is ever missing, you can load the data, split at each 'Certified ...' item in the list, and then write a new file. Ex, for a CSV file:

```
import csv

column_titles = ['Company name', 'Address', 'PO box', etc]
with open('my_csv_file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(column_titles)
    for sub_list in your_split_list:
       writer.writerow(sub_list)
```